# GWT to create utility javascript library

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I need to create javascript library which will be called from other javascript code.

Is it possible to create javascript library using GWT and Java classes? No entry points, no UI - just some utility javascript classes with public static and object methods (e.g. encryption library, image processing library, user input validation library, etc) ?

Any other java to javascript convertion tool is wellcome.

Comment: Check out: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to write GWT code that other JavaScript on the page can call.

However, I don't know of any projects that currently do this in any large scale, so you maybe blazing a new trail.

The basics of calling GWT code from JS is covered in [this GWT blog post from 2008](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html), particularly the section called "Creating JavaScript libraries with GWT" unsurprisingly.

Another project which is linked in that blog post, and maybe of interest to you, is [GWT Exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/), which "contains a generator capable of taking GWT classes and exporting them as ordinary Javascript APIs callable from hand-written Javascript without JSNI"

Answer (score 2):

Check out:

https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/

> Develop an application or library in GWT and use gwtexporter
>   annotations to make classes and methods available from javascript.