# GWT-exporter. Working example

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, gwt-exporter

I have a Java lib and I need to convert it to JS. I found the solution [GWT to create utility javascript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125556/gwt-to-create-utility-javascript-library) to use gwt-exporter. I never used GWT before. I tried [GWT-exporter. Getting started](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/wiki/GettingStarted) but it's not clear how to use it. Simply how to run the project to generate JS?

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.timepedia.exporter</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtexporter</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Java class:

```
import org.timepedia.exporter.client.ExporterUtil;

public class JS implements EntryPoint {
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Export all Exportable classes
    ExporterUtil.exportAll();
}
```

}

Where to find dependency for `EntryPoint`?

Maybe someone can share working example?

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/wiki/GettingStarted
is poor. 
To compile JS I added `gwt-maven-plugin`.

Also I created .gwt.xml file with description of my module.

Following dependency is mandatory

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adding gwt-exporter to your class-path, did you update your module file (application_name.gwt.xml) inheriting the gwt-exporter dependency?.

If so, in this file you should have an entry-point tag pointing to the class to run when the app starts. Open that java file and add the `exportAll` call.

Finally visit all the classes/methods you want to make available in javascript and annotate them appropriately like in the getting started page is indicated