# Java to JavaScript Compiler

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Besides GWT out there, are there other Java to JavaScript Compiler. Currently all my work is done in Java and I heard of Java2Script too. Anyone out there knows other Java to JavaScript?

Comment: You are looking for J2S alternatives? Any specific req.?

Comment: other than it should achieve RIA result. there's nothing else.

Comment: Just curious, is there some reason you don't want to use GWT? Or are you just investigating alternatives just in case? <opinion>If you have to search this hard for alternatives, it can be reasonably assumed that none of them will be as mature as GWT is, so you should probably just stick with GWT</opinion>

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440302/how-to-cross-compile-java-source-code-to-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I believe qooxdoo has a java-javascript compiler. Since they have a similar framework call [QWT](http://qooxdoo.org/contrib/project/qwt) Its similar to GWT but with their own widget set.

Answer (score 1):

Nice list of ..->JavaScript compilers with special chapter dedicated to Java is available here: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#javajvm

Answer (score -3):

In GWT there will be lot of boiler plate codes and learning curve of GWT is high and hard to maintain your code.

Comment: The question is asking for alternatives, and you've just listed the same ones mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: … and now you've edited it to comment about just one of the Java-JS converters listed in the question while sill not suggesting any others (which is what the question asks!)